# Add number to Cell that already has data

Tags: excel, if-statement, addition, vba

I'm trying to add 15 to the total sum of column F for every cell in column "D" that has the word "Total" in it. Obviously I'm going to be adding 45, since there are 3 cells that have "Total" in column "D". But I want this to work for other data that may have more. So far, I have the following (which isn't much):

```
If Right(Range("D" & rowNumber).Value, 5) = "Total" Then
```

It's probably easier than I think it is but I'm stuck after this point. Any help would be much appreciated. This is Excel Visual Basic.Thanks.

Comment: In what setting are you trying to do this? What platform? What language?

Comment: This is Excel Visual Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Total",D1,1)),"Value"+15,"Value")'
```

Keep this formula in F and replace the "value" with your calculation

Answer (score 0):

You should add the correct tags so that people know what language you are using. I am assuming you are working in Excel. If so why not use this? you can change the column references to absolute or relative as needed.

```
=SUMIF(D3:D5,"Total",F3:F5)
```

Comment: sorry :( this is my first time doing this

Comment: No worries. I understand. Now that I see the question was corrected my understanding and answer is way off from what you were asking. Glad you got the answer.